# Excel Macro to copy a table from Excel Sheet and paste it in a PowerPoint Slide with flexibilty to decide which columns and rows

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I want to copy an Excel table and paste it into a Powerpoint slide. The user should be able to decide which columns and rows will be ported, i.e. which columns and rows will be translated to the ppt table. What I get until now is to copy the whole table and paste it but i didn't success to give the user this flexibility to choose the columns and rows.

This is what I wrote:

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()

Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J62")

On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0
    
'Optimize Code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a New Presentation
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

'Add a slide to the Presentation
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

'Copy Excel Range
rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

'Set position:
myShape.Left = 10
myShape.Top = 10

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

can you help me please solve this problem?

thanks a lot!

Comment: you need to let the user to modify the `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J62")` , right ? how do you want the user to select which columns and rows ? by `InputBox` ? By `User_Form` ?

Comment: yes right! And want him to select it by InputBox

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The section below is just an example of a user selecting the number of rows he wants to export (starting Row 1) and number of Columns (starting Column A), you can expand it to whatever you need.

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()

Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim NumofCols   As Variant
Dim NumofRows   As Variant

' select number of rows to export
NumofRows = InputBox("Select number of rows you want to export from table (up to 62)")
If Not IsNumeric(NumofRows) Then
    MsgBox "Please select a valid Numeric value !", vbCritical
    End
Else
   NumofRows = CLng(NumofRows)
End If

' select number of columns you want to expot
NumofCols = InputBox("Select number of columns you want to export from table (up to 10)")
If Not IsNumeric(NumofCols) Then
    MsgBox "Please select a valid Numeric value !", vbCritical
    End
Else
    NumofCols = CLng(NumofCols)
End If

' set the Range starting fro Cell A1 >> you can modify it as you want
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(NumofRows, NumofCols))

On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a New Presentation
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

'Add a slide to the Presentation
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

'Copy Excel Range
rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

'Set position:
myShape.Left = 10
myShape.Top = 10

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```